# Smarty bug that isn't there?

Tags: javascript, css, smarty

I'm getting an error that basically isn't here or i'm super blind because I've been spending the last 30 minutes on it.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught  --&gt; Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template &quot;file:C:\htdocs\smarty\templates\shopify_apps\bundle\js_modules\product_reviews.tpl&quot;  on line 30 &quot;$('head').append('&lt;style&gt; .ratings {position: relative !important;vertical-align: middle!important;display: inline-block!important;color: #b1b1b1!important; overflow: hidden!important;}.full-stars {position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; color: #fde16d;} .empty-stars:before, .full-stars:before {content:&quot;\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605&quot;; font-size: 14pt;}.empty-stars:before {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;}.full-stars:before {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;} @-moz-document url-prefix() {.full-stars {color: #ECBE24;}}&lt;/style&gt;');&quot;  - Unexpected &quot;: &quot;, expected one of: &quot;}&quot; &lt;-- 
  thrown in <b>C:\htdocs\vendor\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

here's the thing that causes it

```
if ($('h1').length) {
  $('h1').after('<span>' + message[1] + '<div class="ratings"><div class="empty-stars"><div class="full-stars" style="width=(avgStars*20)%"></div></div></div></span>');
  $('head').append('<style> .ratings {position: relative !important;vertical-align: middle!important;display: inline-block!important;color: #b1b1b1!important; overflow: hidden!important;}.full-stars {position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; color: #fde16d;}   .empty-stars:before, .full-stars:before {content:"\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605"; font-size: 14pt;}.empty-stars:before {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;}.full-stars:before {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;} @-moz-document url-prefix() {.full-stars {color: #ECBE24;}}</style>');
}
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I'd guess your compiler doesn't like seeing HTML in the JS section even though it's as a string. The JS is actually valid.

Comment: Check your HTML for tags that you didn't close before the script.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your JS code in [`{literal}`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal) tag, if it's on Smarty template file. Your code should be:

```
{literal}
    if ($('h1').length) {
        $('h1').after('<span>' + message[1] + '<div class="ratings"><div class="empty-stars"><div class="full-stars" style="width=(avgStars*20)%"></div></div></div></span>');
        $('head').append('<style> .ratings {position: relative !important;vertical-align: middle!important;display: inline-block!important;color: #b1b1b1!important; overflow: hidden!important;}.full-stars {position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; color: #fde16d;}   .empty-stars:before, .full-stars:before {content:"\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605"; font-size: 14pt;}.empty-stars:before {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;}.full-stars:before {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;} @-moz-document url-prefix() {.full-stars {color: #ECBE24;}}</style>');
    }
{/literal}
```

It should work. If not, please put your full code of Smarty template file in your question, I may help you.

Comment: Link to documentation: https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal